# nodejs response.end() pending in client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response, long-polling

Im trying to build a chat using nodejs and express using long polling technique, 
Im saving for each client the name and the response to end it whenever a message is received, below is the nodejs code:

```
var q = parseQuery(req);
if (q.u){
    client = {};
    client.u = q.u;
    client.res = res;

    clients[q.u] = client;
    clientsLastMessagesMap[q.u] = 0;
}
```

but when the client should get a message, I try to send the response I saved in client object on server side and in the browser I see it never received:

```
 for(var i in clients){
        var messages = "";
        while (clientsLastMessagesMap[clients[i].u] < messagesHistory.length){
            messages += messagesHistory[clientsLastMessagesMap[clients[i].u] ] + ",";
            clientsLastMessagesMap[clients[i].u]++;
        }
        if (messages !== ""){
            console.log( clients[i].u +  " should receive response ");
            clients[i].res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            clients[i].res.end();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with this code. Could it be in your "receive message" function? Have you tried ruling that out (e.g. by pushing to `messagesHistory` and running the loop with a short timeout)?

Comment: what do you mean my "receive message" ?

Comment: "new message" or "push message" might be close. Somewhere you must be accepting/putting new messages, right?

Comment: I currently just try to see the response go back to client, without the logic behind, I checked and saw messages is not equal to "" and I get inside this if, my expectation is to see an empty result go back to client.